# Looping through a user-inputted directory in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

This shell script is supposed to count the number of directories in a user-inputted directory, but it's seemingly not using an inputted directory properly. The output is always 1.

How can I properly have the for loop go through the directory in the variable?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Input a directory
read directory
let var1=0
for FILE in $directory/*/; do
   
   let "var1=var1+1"
done

echo There are $var1 directories
```

Comment: But don't quote the glob characters: `"$directory"/*/`

Answer (score 0):

This is a fixed and expanded version of your script with comment on how it works:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Need extended globbing patterns and non-matching patterns as empty match
shopt -s extglob nullglob

printf %s\\n 'Input a directory'

read -r directory

# assign . (current directory) as default value if empty
directory=${directory:-.}

# Fill array with all directories entries
# that are not . or .. alone
dirs=( "$directory/"?(.)[^.]*/ )

printf '%s\n\n' 'Here are the directories:'

# This prints all the entries of the array
printf %s\\n "${dirs[@]}"

printf '\nThere are %d directories\n' ${#dirs[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    

echo -e "Input a directory:"
read directory

num=$(find "${directory}" -type d | wc -l)

echo -e "There are ${num} directories."
```

Comment: With this method, directories whose name contains a newline character, will count for several entries. You could use `-print0` instead, to get `null` delimited entries that can be counted reliably: `find`: `num=$(find "${directory}" -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -name '.' \! -name '..' -print0 | grep '' -0c)`